# CodeIgniter redirects replacing localhost URL with [::1]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently writing an application where I extend the CI_Controller class and check if a user is logged in, if they aren't I redirect them to the login page.

However, I'm finding that whenever I do this, my the URL it redirects to, changes from localhost/~username/ to [::1]/~username/

The system I'm using is OS X Yosemite and using safari

I've searched everywhere, but with no luck. Any ideas as to the cause of this and how to solve it?

Comment: did you set your base_url in config file ?

Comment: Its because of your base_url is empty.

Comment: On the config.php it says this above base_url `WARNING: You MUST set this value!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your base_url is empty.

Setup the `base_url`

In `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/';
```

Comment: That was the pretty much the problem! I had set set the base_url but I'd missed the http:// Thanks!